# Not getting proper Circular shape of UI Button for iOS 11 (Xcode 9)

Tags: xcode, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, swift4

I have added a button to navigation bar as a custom view. It requires to be circular in shape.
Using the following code:

```
    let infoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
    infoButton.setTitle("₹", for: .normal)
    infoButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    infoButton.clipsToBounds = true
    infoButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5

    let infoItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [infoItem]
```

This had been working fine till now **but not getting proper circular shape in iOS 11 devices**.

Snapshot from device running on **iOS 10:**

[image: 1]

Snapshot from device running on **iOS 11:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create circular view then you don’t need to set clipsToBounds but set masksToBounds to true.

Comment: Didn't help. Also masksToBounds is not the requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

Here I changed the `cornerRadius` and `width`:

```
let infoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 24))
infoButton.setTitle("₹", for: .normal)
infoButton.layer.cornerRadius = infoButton.bounds.size.width / 2
infoButton.clipsToBounds = true
infoButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
```

[image]

Comment: Tried it, still not getting the perfect circular shape.

Comment: Try to increase `width` and try. I checked in `iPad` and `iPhone` its working for me.

Comment: is it an iOS 11 device where you checked? Its working fine for me on all devices running on iOS 10. Issue is in iOS 11 devices.

Comment: Yes, I am checking on iOS11

Comment: Please check I uploaded the result from iOS 11 device.